# How do I process and forward a POST request to an external API using NextRequest and NextResponse?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am struggling to make a post request as my code isn't parsing any `body` on the sever-side of my Next.js app. I feel I'm getting the server-side API wrong.

I'm using Next.js 13's [Route Handers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers) with the `app` directory. This is what my  client-side code looks like:

```
const redirectToCheckout = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("/api/stripe", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: change }),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  console.log(response);
};
```

While the server side looks like this:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRETE_KEY);

export async function POST() {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: NextRequest.body,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ customer });
}
```

Comment: Hi Morris! Did the below answer solve your problem? Feel free to let us know by accepting it :)

Answer (score 2):

As you are sending JSON from the client, you need to parse the request body, and grab the data you need for your Stripe call:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRETE_KEY);

export async function POST(request) {
  const data = await request.json();
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: data.email,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ customer });
}
```

Notice `request` is passed to you as a parameter by Next.js. So no need to import anything.